# There's a bug in my code

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

My code isn't working . I'm trying to figure out what the bug is . Can someone help ? ! It's a function that is supposed to return an array of the first n triangular numbers.

For example, listTriangularNumbers(5) returns [1,3,6,10,15].

```
  function listTriangularNumbers(n) {
    var num;
    var array = [];
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        num = i;
        for (j = i; j >= 1; --j) {
            num = num + j;
        }
        array.push(num);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working? What is it doing? What is it NOT doing that you want it to?

Answer (score 1):

Your initial initialization of `j` is wrong, it's starting at `i` so it's going too high. Also switched the operators around to make sure the conditions work.

```
function listTriangularNumbers(n) {
    var num;
    var array = [];
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        num = i;
        for (j = i-1; j >= 1; j--) {
            num = num + j;
        }
        array.push(num);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to get help:

```js
a = listTriangularNumbers(8);
console.log(a);
function listTriangularNumbers(n) {
    var num;
    var array = [0];
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        num = 0;
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            num = num + j;
        }
        array.push(num);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need 2 for-loops to do this operation. A single for-loop would suffice.

```
function listTriangularNumbers(n) {

  // Initialize result array with first element already inserted
  var result = [1];

  // Starting the loop from i=2, we sum the value of i 
  // with the last inserted element in the array.
  // Then we push the result in the array
  for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    result.push(result[result.length - 1] + i);
  }

  // Return the result
  return result;
}

console.log(listTriangularNumbers(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function listTriangularNumbers(n) {
        var num;
        var array = [];
        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            num = i;
            for (j = i-1; j >= 1; --j) {
                num = num + j;
            }
            array.push(num);
        }
        return array;
    }
    var print=listTriangularNumbers(5);
    console.log(print);
```